# Betting, Required arguement missing?

Tags: discord.py

Im starting a new bot, which I hope can eventually start to allow users to bet. Im having trouble finalising this command as it allows the bot to run but when use the ?Coinflip command it says:

Ignoring exception in command coinflip:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "C:\Users\sambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
>   line 859, in invoke
>       await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\sambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
>   line 718, in invoke
>       await self.prepare(ctx)   File "C:\Users\sambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
>   line 682, in prepare
>       await self._parse_arguments(ctx)   File "C:\Users\sambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
>   line 596, in _parse_arguments
>       transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)   File "C:\Users\sambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
>   line 442, in transform
>       raise MissingRequiredArgument(param) discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guess is a
>   required argument that is missing.

This is the command I am using:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def coinflip(ctx, guess: str, amount: float):
    guesses = ('heads', 'tails')
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess not in guesses:
        await bot.say("Invalid guess.")
        return
    author = ctx.message.author
    balance = get_dollars(author)
    if balance < amount:
        await bot.say("You don't have that much money.  Your balance is ${balance:.2f}")
        return
    result = random.sample(guesses)
    if result == guess:
        await bot.say("You won!")
        add_dollars(author, amount)
    else:
        await bot.say("You lost!")
        remove_dollars(author, amount)
```

Id like it to give a coinflip command which gives off random numbers.

Although it just ignores the command.

Comment: How are you calling the command?  As defined, the command requires that you pass it two arguments, `guess` and `amount`: `?coinflip heads 5.6`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh its literally been copied from GitHub, so im not too sure.

Comment: What did you do that led to you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you aren't passing enough arguments while using this command. You are propably sending `?coinflip` instead of `?coinflip heads 12`.